# Can system apps be enabled/disabled directly from the filesystem?

Tags: applications, settings, internal-storage, boot-loop, kernel

System apps can be disabled by using `pm disable [appname]` and re-enabled in the same fashion. But is there a way to accomplish the same thing by editing some file(s?) somewhere?

Context: My Android-x86 virtual machine is on [boot-loop caused by disabling the Google App](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/187614/4). That's the main reason I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether an app is enabled or disabled is stored in a single file `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml`.

I took the following steps to re-enable the Google App and solve my bootloop problem:

1. Boot the Android-x86 virtual machine in debug mode (i.e. append `DEBUG=2` to the GRUB entry)
2. mount the filesystem:

   ```
   su

   cd /dev    # these are necessary to "refresh" the environment
   cd ..      # otherwise the following commands wouldn't work

   mkdir temp
   mount /dev/block/sda1 temp
   ```
3. Edit the `package-restrictions.xml` file with *vi*:

   ```
   vi /temp/android-6.0-rc1/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml
   ```

   - Find the entry containing `<pkg name="com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox" enabled="3" enabledCaller="com.android.settings">`
   - Move the cursor to the end of that line (Line 13 in my case) and press `a` to begin editing (see [Basic vi commands](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html))
   - Remove the `enabled` and `enabledCaller` attributes. The resulting line should be `<pkg name="com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox">`
   - Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and type `:wq` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit *vi*
4. Type `exit` and hit Enter (twice) to boot to Android normally.

Comment: It is also safe to simply remove the `package-restrictions.xml` file — a new 'clean' file will be recreated on next reboot.